# Nagios - measuring Average CPU Load

Tags: cpu-usage, nagios

I've been looking for some hours now for a plugin that will notify me if one of my server's CPU Load has been over 90% for the past 5 hours.
No luck looking around the Nagios Exchange.

Can anyone help out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

CPU load under UNIX is typically defined as the number of processes in a runnable state.  We measure this in 1, 5, and 15 minute intervals. The command `uptime` is a common way to output the load average values.

> ~$ uptime   18:35:22 up 1 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.04, 0.01,
>   0.01

[check_load](https://www.nagios-plugins.org/doc/man/check_load.html) takes a tuple of three elements, matching the 1, 5, and 15 minute averages and accepts both a warning and critical threshold.

As a rough idea, try `check_load -c 0.9,0.9,0.9` with a `check_interval` of 1 hour and a `max_check_attempts` of 5.

Also note, the `-r` argument.  This addresses the fact that most CPUs are multi-core and can therefore be fully utilized individually while still having excess capacity in the aggregate.

Answer (score 2):

The basic check_load Nagios check will only evaluate `/proc/loadavg` which just has 1, 5, and 15 minute averages. If you need more, you would need a backlog reaching this far. Incidentally, the `sysstat` package does just that - it evaluates and records performance values at given intervals and makes them available via the `sar` command line utility. The <strike>[check_sa Nagios plugin](https://github.com/jgoldschrafe/check_sa)</strike> is capable of evaluating the output and averaging the values to match your needs.

I should add that Nagios is a rather poor choice when it comes to actually defining alarm thresholds based on performance values averaging over a certain period of time as this needs extensive state-keeping which Nagios does not support. Other monitoring systems collecting performance data are doing a better job here. I would suggest looking at [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/) or at least something like [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) if you can't manage the complexity and handle the technical requirements (SNMP) of the former. Both have the advantage of being able to draw fancy RRD graphs helping you to detect trends before you get them formalized in evaluation rules.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Actually I'm a Zabbix guy. I'd set this up in a matter of minutes on Zabbix as it supports a very simple arithmetic syntax. That's no where to be found on Nagios I'm afraid.

About sysstat and sar, I'm not very sure I follow. Eventually is the check_sa plugin all I need or what?

Comment: @user1571299 you'll need the `sysstat` package on the monitored host, the `check_sa` plugin and a way to execute it remotely (e.g. NRPE)

Comment: i guess its a poor choice if your farm is more than 10,000 servers... otherwise at ~10 checks per host...... its 15-20 minutes to cycle thru them depending

Comment: @nandoP what is? Munin? The check_sa plugin? Nagios?

Answer (score 1):

Astonishing - isn`t it?

We had to write a monitor ourselves for this, too.

The standard check_load is pretty meaningless since it has to be set into relationship with the number of (logical) processors within the system.

So roughly what we do:
- look up how many processors are reported in the system
- divide the current load through that number

There you will get that 90% mark you are after.

We use 100% for warning and 150% for critical.

Answer (score 0):

> install systat
> crontab sa -q 10000000 |mail somewhere@youwant.report.com

basically, sar gives you by default 10 minute status details,.

so for load avg...

> [root@ops2 ~]# sar -q|tail -5
>
> 05:00:01 PM         0       527      0.00      0.01      0.00
>
> 05:10:01 PM         1       528      0.00      0.00      0.00
>
> 05:20:01 PM         6       537      0.00      0.00      0.00
>
> 05:30:01 PM         2       532      0.00      0.01      0.00
>
> Average:            2       529      0.03      0.05      0.04

this can report on a number of things, although email server reporting is going away in the likes of app dynamics and newrelic, which dig much deeper (but cost money)

IMHO, nagios is still the best for the money... and hell you can even integrate it with ircd

nagios is definately the way i would go.  it is easy to use their prebuilt plugins, or write your own nrpe plugins, and it awesome with hipchat, irc, pagerduty, or custom alerting systems

Comment: Can you add some detail on how this answers the question?

Comment: is that better?  what about puppetmaster can on they fly make your nagios conf.... now we have a good post!